# Erase cookie variable in another route in cookie-session

Tags: express, cookies, session-cookies

Lets say I have simple page that stores how many times the page has been viewed in a cookie (code coming from cookie-session github readme):

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // Update views
  req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1

  // Write response
  res.end(req.session.views + ' views')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Then I want to create another route which would simply erease counter on that previous route:

```
app.get('/d', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.views = 0
    console.log(req.session.views)
});
```

However doing this I still get number of views counted on that `'/'` route while on `'/d'` route it is 0.
How can I change cookie session params of one route from another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're not sending any response in your second route, which according to the docs (https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session#cookiesessionoptions) means no cookie will be sent back and your session will remain unchanged.

So, your route erasing the counter should probably look like this:

```
app.get('/d', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.views = 0
  res.end('View counter has been reset to 0')
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it sill shows current amount of view from `'/'` route

Comment: hmm, you did restart the app, didn't you? if so, could you post the entire listing maybe, so I could try to reproduce?

Comment: Yeah i placed req.session.views inside if else statement so it didnt update properly.